# Recebendo dados de um Streaming

Tags: php, socket, streaming

estou com um pequeno probleminha e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.
Recentemente eu tive uma duvida e comecei a pesquisar a respeito mas não achei nada, notei que os serviços de streaming de vídeo usa um servidor "wowza" e pra isso queria receber o streaming e poder replicar usando php um exemplo é o url a baixo

> http://live-hls.rtvcm.stream.flumotion.com:80/rtvcm/hls-multi/main.m3u8

usei esse codigo pra tentar conectar mas ficou dando erro

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("http://live-hls.rtvcm.stream.flumotion.com:80/rtvcm/hls-multi/main.m3u8", 80, $errno, $errstr);

fwrite($fp, "GET request HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");

while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 1024);
}
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

não sei se é possível, tentei usar socket mas não consegui, alguém poderia me ajudar nisso? me desculpem caso não seja apropriado o url mas eu precisava citar um url pra testes.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, sei que essa pergunta já foi a um bom tempo atrás, mas para fins de histórico e outras pessoas com dúvidas similares segue a minha resposta.

Um stream HLS nada mais é do que uma série de requisições HTTP (ou HTTPS), isto porque o stream é segmentado em pequenas partes (exemplo: pequenos vídeos/audios de 30 segundos). Dessa forma, os browsers conseguem consumir o stream sem precisar abrir conexões TCP/UDP como ocorria em streams RTMP/RTSP via Flash.

Sendo assim, se você quiser fazer algum tipo de cache deste stream, para que os seus usuários não batam direto no Wowza (upstream/origin), você poderia simplesmente colocar um proxy reverso (NGinx por exemplo) na frente, o que seria bem mais eficiente do que implementar este proxy em PHP. Outra solução que seria muito mais robusta seria utilizar uma CDN para realizar o cache e entrega deste stream - mas isso vai gerar custos mais altos, então precisa ser considerado bem.

Posso compartilhar alguns exemplos de configuração do NGinx caso alguém tenha interesse no futuro.

Comment: Se possível, coloque exemplos que demonstrem a solução dada ou que comprovem o funcionamento da mesma. Se não for possível, cite referências para que o usuário possa saber como começar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, pensei em fazer em uma linguagem porque possibilita escalar com mais facilidade, isso foi somente um teste que eu estava testando para ver a possibilidade, você poderia postar algum exemplo? pode ser em qualquer linguagem